# How to extract lat, long coordinates from Geography type column in dataframe using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgis, postgresql, geopandas, geoalchemy-2

This is the SQL command that works perfectly.

```
SELECT lonlat,
ST_Y(lonlat::geometry) AS latitude,
ST_X(lonlat::geometry) AS longitude
```

This is the output of the SQL command.

```
lonlat                                              latitude        longitude
0101000020E6100000AEF1DA73AB3B57C0339E6D10A1054540  42.0439777885   -92.9323396338
0101000020E610000031FC5F712BA156C091D7021BDEC64440  41.5536531223   -90.5182765424
0101000020E61000008CA19C6857E156C0A4AF74B31BD34440  41.6492828674   -91.52096
```

I'm trying to emulate this SQL command with Python instead, using modules pandas, sqlalchemy, and geoalchemy2.

```
from sqlalchemy import func
from sqlalchemy import cast
import geoalchemy2 as ga2
from geoalchemy2 import Geography, Geometry
import pandas as pd

geography1 = '0101000020E6100000AA32C49407E357C017BF3A136EBB4440'
geography2 = '0101000020E610000031FC5F712BA156C091D7021BDEC64440'

# create a dataframe 
data = {'lonlat': [geography1, geography2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['lonlat'])

# use the 'lonlat' column to create 'longitude' and 'latitude' columns 
df['longitude'] = df.lonlat.apply(func.ST_Y)
df['latitude'] = df.lonlat.apply(func.ST_X)

print(df)
```

This is the output of the Python program

```
                                              lonlat      longitude       latitude
0  0101000020E6100000AA32C49407E357C017BF3A136EBB...  ST_Y(:ST_Y_1)  ST_X(:ST_X_1)
1  0101000020E610000031FC5F712BA156C091D7021BDEC6...  ST_Y(:ST_Y_1)  ST_X(:ST_X_1)
```

Clearly, the longitude and latitude columns do not contain coordinates. I've tried casting lonlat into a Geometry column. I've tried using ST_AsText(). I'm just very confused overall, but I think the problem has to do with casting.

Answer (score 0):

If you write it like this

```
geography1 = '0101000020E6100000AA32C49407E357C017BF3A136EBB4440'
geography2 = '0101000020E610000031FC5F712BA156C091D7021BDEC64440'
```

then pandas interprets it as standard Python string.

So you have to execute a real select and fetch those values and assign them to your example variables such that they have the right type.

For testing you could even use a simple select expression without `from` clause,  such as:

```
c = db.execute('''select
  ST_X('0101000020E6100000AA32C49407E357C017BF3A136EBB4440'::geography(point,4326)::geometry) as longitude,
  ST_Y('0101000020E6100000AA32C49407E357C017BF3A136EBB4440'::geography(point,4326)::geometry) as latitude''')
```

For querying a real table you modify it like this:

```
c = db.execute('''select
  ST_X(some_loc_col::geometry) as longitude,
  ST_Y(some_loc_col::geometry) as latitude, some_other_col from mytable''')
```

Or if you have to execute the select statement multiple times you can prepare it with `sqlalchemy.sql.text()`.

The `func.ST_*` expressions are only useful when dealing with the SQLAlchemy API, e.g. when preparing/building statements using Python expressions, i.e. they can't be called from Python code such as Pandas.

So the basic idea is to convert geography column to long/lat columns as part of the select expression for consumption in Python.